# comparing values of composed types in Microsoft Word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a Microsoft Word macro, I tried to create an ordered list of persons with some data attached to each (for example age).

I created a class module called `CPersonName` like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public LastName As String
Public FirstName As String
```

In a `Sub` (macro), I have this code:

```
Dim PersonA As CPersonNamne, PersonB As CPersonNamne, PersonsWithData As Object
Set PersonA = New CPersonNamne
Set PersonB = New CPersonNamne
Set PersonsWithData = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
PersonA.LastName = "Smith"
PersonA.FirstName = "Sven"
PersonB.LastName = "Miller"
PersonB.FirstName = "Tom"
PersonsWithData.Add PersonA, 77
PersonsWithData.Add PersonB, 18
```

But the macro fails at the last line (when trying to insert the second person into the sorted list). Microsoft Word complains about not being able to compare 2 elements. Of course, the program must compare PersonA with PersonB to know which one should be first in the list. The obvious way would be to compare them elementwise.  (Which means that it should compare lastnames, and, if lastnames are equal, compare fistnames.) But if Microsoft Word does not do that implicitly, I would have to define operator "<" for CPersonName. How is that done?

I have 2 ugly alternatives:

1. Using a string of for example 200 characters, where the first 100
   characters are the last-name (right-padded with spaces) and the last
   100 characters are the first-name (right-padded with spaces) and
   then use such strings as keys in the sorted list.
2. Inserting the persons into an array instead, implementing insertion sort.

Is that the best that can be done in
    Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go by:

1. adding `Age` as a member of your class
2. using a combination of `LastName` and `FirstName` as the `key`

as follows

- Class code

  ```
  Public LastName As String
  Public FirstName As String
  Public Age As Long
  ```
- your sub code

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub main()

      Dim PersonA As CPersonName, PersonB As CPersonName

      Set PersonA = New CPersonName
      Set PersonB = New CPersonName

      Dim PersonsWithData As Object
      Set PersonsWithData = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

      With PersonA
          .LastName = "Smith"
          .FirstName = "Sven"
          .Age = 77
      End With

      With PersonB
          .LastName = "Miller"
          .FirstName = "Tom"
          .Age = 18
      End With

      PersonsWithData.Add PersonA.LastName & PersonA.FirstName, PersonA
      PersonsWithData.Add PersonB.LastName & PersonB.FirstName, PersonB


      Dim i As Long
      With PersonsWithData
          For i = 0 To .Count - 1
              Debug.Print .getkey(i), .GetByIndex(i).Age
          Next
      End With
  End Sub
  ```

  which outputs:

  ```
  MillerTom      18 
  SmithSven      77
  ```

Comment: That is the fist of the ugly alternatives that I mentioned, but without the patdding that is necessary to make it work:
BondeAdam
BondJames
With suficcient padding, it does work:
Bond James
BondeAdam 

My code now implements my second ugly alternative; insertion sort.